# Can not connect to vsftpd FTP server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, ssl, filezilla

I installed vsftpd on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Linux box.  When I try to connect either locally using the URL *ftp://localhost* I do get an authentication dialog box.  However, after I enter my user name and password the authentication box comes right back in an instant, asking me again for login details.

**USE NOTES**: I am *definitely* restarting the vsftpd service between tests using: *sudo service vsftpd restart*.  Also, my use/security context is to provide an easy centralized file sharing repository for my local network.  I have no desire to open the FTP server to the web or any other system but those stations on my local network that are behind the same, lone router.

If I try logging in from another station on the local network, using the latest version of FileZilla, I get a connection time-out error message.  I think it's *kind of* working because if I try to connect using plain FTP (no SSL), I get a 530 error telling me that non-anonymous users must use SSL.  But again, when I try to connect using SSL, I get the time-out.

I've got vsftpd setup using the settings from this link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=518293&p=3138955#post3138955

The ones I used are:

```
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
```

And:

```
# Show hidden files and the "." and ".." folders.
# Useful to not write over hidden files:
force_dot_files=YES

# Hide the info about the owner (user and group) of the files.
# hide_ids=YES

# Connection limit for each IP:
max_per_ip=2

# Maximum number of clients:
max_clients=20
```

And I found this on a Linux forum, to set the root FTP directory:

```
# FTP root directory.
local_root=/home/roschler/Documents/ftproot
```

And I found this in a Linux forum post on vsftpd:

```
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

I had an allowed users list but I disabled it for now.

```
#userlist_deny=NO
#userlist_enable=YES
#userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users
```

When I look in */var/log/vsftpd.log* I do see each connection attempt, both from localhost and from the remote station on the same network.  What's odd is that I *don't* see any error messages.  No connection failures, authentication failures, nothing.  Just:

```
Tue Feb 23 21:44:52 2016 [pid 5325] CONNECT: Client
```

Followed by the IP address.

But no luck so far logging in.  Can anyone tell me how to get this working?  Is it:

- A firewall issue?  If so, why do I get the 530 error message when I attempt to login remotely using non-SSL FTP?
- A directory permissions issue, so vsftpd is failing internally when it tries to switch to the FTP directory?
- What?

Comment: I know this is almost obvious but you only said _"I enter my user name and password"_; are those the couple for the _Ubuntu 14.04 LTS_ system?. If _sshd_ demon is up and you try to connect to the box via _ssh_ are you successful? Did you try with `sftp://localhost` ?

Comment: Does adding `local_enable=YES`, and `log_ftp_protocol=YES`, provide any more functionality/logging?

Comment: @Hastur I *can* connect via an SSH client using the user name and password.  Some login details fail with vsftpd login.

Comment: @Castaglia Just tried that.  No luck.  No new information in log.